# Two HP DL165 servers locking up randomly, switching fans to high

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant

I have a pair of HP DL165 G7 ProLiant blade servers at home.  I purchased them used, so no support remaining.  One is running a FreeBSD system (FreeNAS 9.10) and one is running Linux (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS), both bare-metal installs.  They are largely identical dual-12-core AMD systems with 48GB RAM; the peripherals differ slightly (hard drives, TV input card, etc) for the different uses.

On random and fairly rare occasions, I come home to find both servers unresponsive and the fans on at full speed, similar to the initial power-on state.  It is always both units, not just one.  I have not paid attention to the front panel LEDs other than that they are no longer flashing. No red lights. Local keyboard and monitor are also unresponsive.  No messages at all in any log files; they just end abruptly with no indication of a problem.  To reset, I have to hold in the power button to shut off, then turn them back on.  They have come back each time with no issue.

Assuming it was random power glitches, I purchased a UPS (Tripp-Lite) and power them through there, on separate switched outputs.  This lockup condition still occurred once afterward, but there was nothing I could attribute the fault to.  The UPS didn't report any glitches, but I thought maybe it was too small for it to pick up. It happens so infrequently I couldn't isolate the issue.

Last night, power went out completely and the system switched over to battery power normally.  After 10 minutes of battery runtime and with about 60%+ battery still remaining, I was standing in front of the rack and about to initiate shutdown when I heard something (I believe the UPS) strain VERY briefly (like a quick buzz) and both systems kicked into this locked state.

It happens maybe once or twice a month at most, so I can't pinpoint anything.  Both systems are running at low utilization (FreeNAS almost always less than 1.0 and the Ubuntu system constantly around 2.0).

As the system was on battery power, input feed should have been glitch-free coming from the UPS inverter.  Because whatever it is causes both servers to go down, even though there is little in common, what could be the problem?  Randomly failing power supply pulling down the input to brownout levels?

Is this failure mode (unresponsive with fans on high) a documented issue?  I haven't found any examples of this, but perhaps I'm using the wrong search terms.

Comment: Is your ILO configured?

Comment: I haven't explored the ILO interface at all because the units came without the management card.  I just assumed the units weren't capable of out-of-band management.  But, looking at the ILO docs again, it appears I could use a shared network port or serial interface on the G7.